# Recyler View with multiple toggle button checking the button randomly on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a recycler view with with multiple toggle buttons on click of which the state is changed and the newly updated state is sent to the server by calling a service on changing the state of the toggle button.
The problem i am facing is that whenever the recycler view is scrolled the toggle buttons are getting checked randomly because of the recycling of the views and the service is called multiple times at the same time, because of which an indeterminate progress bar is shown.
I have tried multiple ways to handle this by intially setting the adapter to null. and also storing the state of the checked/toggle state of the button. 
But nothing seems to help.

Below is the code of the recycler adapter class

```
public class NotificationsIllnessAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationsIllnessAdapter.NotificationIllnessViewHolder> {

Context context = null;
ArrayList<NotificationIllnessdata> notificationIllnessdatas;

ArrayList<NotificationIllnessdata> notificationIllnessArraylist = null;

NetworkStatus mNetworkStatus = null;

static AlertDialog mShowDialog = null;

Button mButton_alerts;


public NotificationsIllnessAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<NotificationIllnessdata> notificationIllnessdataArrayList,Button button_alerts) {
    this.context = context;
    this.notificationIllnessdatas=notificationIllnessdataArrayList;
    this.mButton_alerts=button_alerts;

    for(int i=0;i<this.notificationIllnessdatas.size();i++)
    {
        Log.e("nIllnessadapter","inside constructor"+this.notificationIllnessdatas.get(i).getIsNotification());

    }
}

@Override
public NotificationIllnessViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    mNetworkStatus = new NetworkStatus(context);
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notifications_inflater, parent, false);

    notificationIllnessArraylist = new ArrayList<>();

    NotificationIllnessViewHolder viewHolder = new NotificationIllnessViewHolder(context,v);
    viewHolder.setClickListener(new MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClickListener(View v, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"OnClick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final NotificationIllnessViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.mTextView_symptom.setText(notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).getIllnessCategory());

    if(notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).getIsNotification())
    {
        Log.e("nIllnessadapter","true"+position);
        holder.mToggleButton_symptom.setChecked(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("nIllnessadapter","false"+position);
        holder.mToggleButton_symptom.setChecked(false);
    }

    //in some cases, it will prevent unwanted situations
    holder.mToggleButton_symptom.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    //if true the togglebutton will be selected else unselected.
    holder.mToggleButton_symptom.setChecked(notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).getIsNotification());

    holder.mToggleButton_symptom.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


        ArrayList<UpdateNotificationRequestData> Updatenoti;

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
            {
                //toggle button enabled

                UpdateNotificationsRequestModel requestModel = new UpdateNotificationsRequestModel();
                requestModel.setUserID(AppPreferences.readString(context, AppPreferenceNames.sUserid,""));
                requestModel.setAppVersion(CommonUtils.APP_VERSION);
                requestModel.setDeviceInfo(CommonUtils.DeviceInfo);
                requestModel.setDeviceTypeID(CommonUtils.DEVICE_TYPE_ID);
                Updatenoti = new ArrayList<UpdateNotificationRequestData>();
                UpdateNotificationRequestData requestData = new UpdateNotificationRequestData();

                Log.e("illadapter","status-->"+notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).getIsNotification());

                requestData.setIsNotification("1");
                requestData.setNotificationSettingID(notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).getNotificationSettingID());
                Updatenoti.add(requestData);
                requestModel.setUpdateNotification(Updatenoti);


                /**
                 * Call the Update Notifications service
                 */


                if (mNetworkStatus.isNetWorkAvailable(context) == true) {
                    update_notifications(requestModel);
                } else {
                    CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(context,"No Network Available. Please connect to network");
                }

                //set the objects last status
                holder.mToggleButton_symptom.setChecked(isChecked);

            }
            else
            {
                //toggle button disabled

                UpdateNotificationsRequestModel requestModel = new UpdateNotificationsRequestModel();
                requestModel.setUserID(AppPreferences.readString(context, AppPreferenceNames.sUserid,""));
                requestModel.setAppVersion(CommonUtils.APP_VERSION);
                requestModel.setDeviceInfo(CommonUtils.DeviceInfo);
                requestModel.setDeviceTypeID(CommonUtils.DEVICE_TYPE_ID);
                Updatenoti = new ArrayList<UpdateNotificationRequestData>();
                UpdateNotificationRequestData requestData = new UpdateNotificationRequestData();

                Log.e("illadapter","status 2-->"+notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).getIsNotification());

                requestData.setIsNotification("0");
                requestData.setNotificationSettingID(notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).getNotificationSettingID());
                Updatenoti.add(requestData);
                requestModel.setUpdateNotification(Updatenoti);

                /**
                 * Call the UpdateNotifications service
                 */

                if (mNetworkStatus.isNetWorkAvailable(context) == true) {
                    update_notifications(requestModel);
                } else {
                    CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(context,"No Network Available. Please connect to network");
                }

                //set the objects last status
                holder.mToggleButton_symptom.setChecked(false);
            }

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return notificationIllnessdatas.size();
}


/**
 * View Holder for Adapter
 */
class NotificationIllnessViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    MyClickListener clickListener;
    public TextView mTextView_symptom;
    public ToggleButton mToggleButton_symptom;

    public NotificationIllnessViewHolder(Context context,View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mTextView_symptom = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_Symptom);
        mToggleButton_symptom = (ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton_Symptoms);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // If not long clicked, pass last variable as false.
        clickListener.onClickListener(v, getPosition(), false);
    }

    public void setClickListener(MyClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

}

/**
 * Update the notification settings
 */
public void update_notifications(UpdateNotificationsRequestModel object) {
    /**
     * Start the progress Bar.
     */
    CommonUtils.show_progressbar(context);

    /**
     * call api
     */

    Call<UpdateNotificationsResponseModel> responsecall = VirusApplication.getRestClient().getAPIService().updateNotifications(object);
    responsecall.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateNotificationsResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<UpdateNotificationsResponseModel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            /**
             * Stop the progress Bar
             */
            CommonUtils.stop_progressbar();

            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                //Server Success
                UpdateNotificationsResponseModel responseModel = response.body();
                if (responseModel.getErrorCode().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    //Data Success
                    Log.e("nf", "data success");
                    //CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(context, responseModel.getMessage());

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setMessage(responseModel.getMessage())
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    /**
                                     * Downloads mychildren details.
                                     */
                                    if (mNetworkStatus.isNetWorkAvailable(context)) {
                                        getNotificationSettings();
                                    } else {
                                        CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(context, context.getString(R.string.network_unavailable));
                                    }



                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    mShowDialog = builder.create();
                    mShowDialog.show();





                } else {
                    CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(context, responseModel.getMessage());
                }
            } else {

                CommonUtils.showAlertDialog(context, "Server Error");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

            /**
             * Stop the progress Bar
             */
            CommonUtils.stop_progressbar();


        }
    });
}


/**
 * Get Notification Settings
 */
public void getNotificationSettings(){

    //hit the getnotifications API to fetch the notification details

    CommonUtils.show_progressbar(context);

    /**
     * Calls WebAPI
     */
    Call<NotificationsModel> notificationsModelCall = VirusApplication.getRestClient().getAPIService().notifications(getNotificationsrequest());
    notificationsModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<NotificationsModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<NotificationsModel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            /**
             * Stops the Progresss bar
             */
            CommonUtils.stop_progressbar();

            if(response.isSuccess()) {

                NotificationsModel notificationsModel = response.body();
                if (notificationsModel.getErrorCode().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {// Data Success

                    Log.e("notificationsAdapter","data success");

                    int i = 1;
                    notificationIllnessArraylist.clear();
                    for (NotificationIllnessdata notificationIllnessdata : notificationsModel.getNotificationIllnessdata()) {
                        notificationIllnessArraylist.add(notificationIllnessdata);

                        Log.e("notificationsAdapter","getnotificationsmethod"+i     +notificationIllnessdata.getIsNotification()   );

                        i++;
                    }

                    Log.e("sonu", "Symptoms ArraySize-->" + notificationIllnessArraylist.size());

                    if (notificationIllnessArraylist.size() > 0) {

                        ArrayList<NotificationIllnessdata> arrayTrue = new ArrayList<NotificationIllnessdata>();

                        ArrayList<NotificationIllnessdata> arrayFalse = new ArrayList<NotificationIllnessdata>();


                        for(int j=0;j<notificationIllnessArraylist.size();j++)
                        {

                            if(notificationIllnessArraylist.get(j).getIsNotification()){
                                arrayTrue.add(notificationIllnessArraylist.get(j));
                            }
                            else
                            if(!notificationIllnessArraylist.get(j).getIsNotification())
                            {
                                arrayFalse.add(notificationIllnessArraylist.get(j));
                            }
                        }

                        if(notificationIllnessArraylist.size()==arrayTrue.size())
                        {
                            mButton_alerts.setText("DeSelect All");
                            mButton_alerts.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.togglebutton_on);
                        }
                        else
                        if(notificationIllnessArraylist.size()==arrayFalse.size())
                        {
                            mButton_alerts.setText("Select All");
                            mButton_alerts.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.togglebutton_off);
                        }
                        else {
                            mButton_alerts.setText("Select All");
                            mButton_alerts.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.togglebutton_off);
                        }


                    }



                }
            }




        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}

/**
 * Request values to Get notifications.
 *
 * @return map object
 */
public Map<String, Object> getNotificationsrequest() {

    Map<String, Object> getChildrenValues = new HashMap<>();
    getChildrenValues.put("appVersion", CommonUtils.APP_VERSION);
    getChildrenValues.put("deviceTypeID", CommonUtils.DEVICE_TYPE_ID);
    getChildrenValues.put("deviceInfo", CommonUtils.DeviceInfo);
    getChildrenValues.put("userID", AppPreferences.readString(context, AppPreferenceNames.sUserid, ""));

    return getChildrenValues;

   }


  }
```

Please help me with this. Have been trying from many days but haven't found any solution even after following many answers  on stack overflow.

Comment: Instead of check changed, why don't you implement click event and **onClick()** check the button state.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this :

```
    public class NotificationsIllnessAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationsIllnessAdapter.NotificationIllnessViewHolder> {
    Context context = null;
    ArrayList<NotificationIllnessdata> notificationIllnessdatas;
    NetworkStatus mNetworkStatus = null;
    static AlertDialog mShowDialog = null;
    Button mButton_alerts;

    public NotificationsIllnessAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<NotificationIllnessdata> notificationIllnessdataArrayList,Button button_alerts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mNetworkStatus = new NetworkStatus(context);
        this.notificationIllnessdatas=notificationIllnessdataArrayList;
        this.mButton_alerts=button_alerts;
    }

    @Override
    public NotificationIllnessViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.notifications_inflater, parent, false);
        NotificationIllnessViewHolder viewHolder = new NotificationIllnessViewHolder(context,v);
        return viewHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final NotificationIllnessViewHolder holder, final int position) {

       holder.mTextView_symptom.setText(notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).getIllnessCategory());

      holder.mToggleButton_symptom.setChecked(notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).getIsNotification());

        holder.mToggleButton_symptom.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            ArrayList<UpdateNotificationRequestData> Updatenoti;
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                 int position = getAdapterPosition();
                 if( position == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION ) {
                    return;
                 }
                if(isChecked)
                {

        notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).setNotification(true);

                }
                else
                {
       notificationIllnessdatas.get(position).setNotification(false);

                }
            }

        });
    }
```

The toggling of checkboxes / toggle buttons happens due to the fact that the states are not maintained in your model class. You already have a isNotification field in your model class, set it as soon as the toggle happens as I've illustrated in the code. I have other code clean up suggestions, but those can wait.

Let me know if you need more clarifications.

> Update : Answer only applicable for retaining states of toggle
>   buttons.

Comment: Thanks for  the code. I tried it but still I am facing the same issue. As of what i observed its happening because 2 service calls are happening simultaneously because of different toggle buttons getting checked on scroll. please can you help?

Comment: I am using a recycler view, so when the views are getting recycled the state of the buttons is lost.

Comment: Its because of the recycling of views, you need to maintain the states of your toggle button in model class.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to make a network call as soon as there is a toggle of buttons? Can't you trigger it using an external button? Since we have a check change trigger every time the view is recycled, the network call happens

Comment: //set the objects last status
holder.mToggleButton_symptom.setChecked(isChecked); Im already saving the objects last status by this statement.  It is necessary to make the network call as soon as the button is toggled.

Comment: That won't work, you'll have to save it in the model class.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127150/discussion-between-alok-omkar-and-rachana).